# UPDATE не работает

Tags: mysqli, php, sql

Здравствуйте. Не работает UPDATE запрос. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$admin = new db();
$catid = $_GET['catid'];
if($id>0){
    $game_edit = mysqli_fetch_array($game_ed);
  echo $game_edit['name'];
  $categ = $game_edit['categ'];
    if($_FILES){
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $text = $_POST['text'];
     $image = $_FILES['orig']['name'];
     $sl1 = $_FILES['sl1']['name'];
     $sl2 = $_FILES['sl2']['name'];
     $sl3 = $_FILES['sl3']['name'];
     $background =  $_FILES['back']['name'];
     $back_color = $_POST['bg_color'];
     $logo = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
     $url = $_POST['url'];
    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['orig']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/game_img/".$image);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['back']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/bg/".$background);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sl1']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/slider_game/".$sl1);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sl2']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/slider_game/".$sl2);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sl3']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/slider_game/".$sl3);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'],"../image/game/slider_game/".$logo);
    $admin->updategame($id,$name,$text,$image,$background,$back_color,$logo,$categ,$url);
    }
}
}
```

Вот сам запрос:

```
function updategame($id,$name,$text,$image,$background,$back_color,$logo,$categ,$url){
        $sql = mysqli_query($this->connect(), "UPDATE game SET name=$name ,desc=$text, image=$image,bg_game=$background,bg_color=$back_color,logo=$logo,categ=$categ,url=$url WHERE id=$id");

      }
```

Comment: @fikos, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

P.S. у Вас используется ключевое слово desc без ковычек. Это запрещено

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в ошибку. Проблема была в запросе:

```
function updategame($id,$name,$text,$image,$background,$back_color,$logo,$categ,$url){
        $sql = mysqli_query($this->connect(), "UPDATE `game` SET `name`='$name' ,`desc`='$text', `image`='$image',`bg_game`='$background',`bg_color`='$back_color',`logo`='$logo',`categ`='$categ',`url`='$url' WHERE `id`='$id'");

}
```